# How to add date picker in android

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to add date picker in android app. When I drag and drop the date picker error is shown on the screen. The error is -

"The following classes could not be found:
- CalendarView (Change to android.widget.CalendarView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- DatePicker (Change to android.widget.DatePicker, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)"

Following is the xml code of datepicker -

```
<DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="83dp"
        android:layout_y="72dp" />
```

I am new to Android. Please Help.

Comment: I did not understand. Can you please explain where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be previewing your screen on Android Target 16 or higher. Try using Android Target 15 for Graphic Layout Editor (android icon on the top, in ADT 20). Looks like there is issue with Android Target 16.

You don't need to set the project target just the target in the `graphical layout editor`.